# How to transfer changes from one branch to another if file name changed?

Tags: java, git, intellij-idea

I have branch a, where I'm work with file1. Another man work with similar branch b. He made many changes there and renamed file1 to file2. I should checkout to his branch and transfer my changes to his branch. How can I do this? As I understand, stash is not a solution, because file name changed and after stash applying file doesn't appear. How to transfer changes from that file1(branch a) to file2(branch b)?

Comment: Git _normally_ can detect renames, as long as the file didn't change too much.

Comment: How it's to apply for my situation? When I changed branch changes were not transferred to another branch...

Comment: Ah... what? When you switch branches, files and contents will be the way that they are on the tip of the branches. As long as you haven't merged (or rebased, or cherry-picked) you won't _magically_ see things happen.

Comment: Let's return to the question. So, how I can resolve this situation?

Comment: @virus_dmk what happens when you try to merge the other branch into yours?  You may want to look into Git's [rename detection](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#Documentation/git-config.txt-mergerenames).  There are some knobs there, but I'm not sure if it'll be enough in your case.  There's no easy answer here as you two are in conflict, and that comes with the need to resolve it.  That's very dependent on the situation, so we can't step you through that.  FWIW, my personal workflow would be to rebase my changes onto his branch... but if you're new to it, that can land you in a mess too.

Answer (score 1):

#### Use `git merge`, `git pull` or `git cherry-pick` as you would normally would

...to bring changes from one branch to another. Git is usually smart about detecting the name changes and will merge the changes *and* the name change. If there is a conflict, you will have to handle it. It can be a little confusing, so using a good merge tool helps.